# selenium firefoxdriver tests can`t click button

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, webdriver

Im using selenium and firefox driver and I cant make `<span>close</span>`button to click. I have tryed different aproaches:

1 selelenium.mouseDownAt("link=close", "10,10");
 selelenium.mouseUpAt("link=close", "10,10");

2 driver.findElementByPartialLinkText("close").click();

3 selelenium.focus("link=close");
            seleleniumkeyPress("link=close", "r");

4 actions.click(driver.findElementByPartialLinkText("close")).perform();
           actions.release(driver.findElementByPartialLinkText("close")).perform();

but it does not work. only effect that I can see is that the button seems to be clicked and hold down, but there is no release. thats why I have try to do it by method 1 and 4.

but still I havend been able to just click it so a popup could be seen.

anyone have an idea what might be the cause?

html code:

```
<div id="id_asd83221" class="sub-tbl-content sub_position">             
     <div class="sub-order-pos-firstpart">       
      <div class="float pic-content sub-img sub-img-arrow-down"></div>      
       <div class="float sp_id_content">some text</div>    
         <div class="float type-sub-content">some text</div>     
        <div class="float amount-sub-content">some text</div>   
          <div class="float pl-sub-title">some text</div>      
       <div class="float pl-sub-content">some text</div>     
       </div>     
        <div>           
  <div class="float"><a class="small-tbl-button  sp_close_positon_btn" href="#">
<span>close</span></a></div>      
       <div class="floatright edit-sub-content">
<a class="sp_edit_position_link" href="#">some text</a></div>                                                                                                    </div>           
  <div class="clear0"></div>     
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem that every your example clicks on , but should be on .
Try to use xpath //a/.[contains(text(),'close')]/..
Or you also may try to turn on Enable Native Events.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a[class='sp_close_positon_btn'] span")).Click();
```